# Expected number of games in a best of 7 series

Tags: probability, expectation

Assuming each team has a 0.5 probability of winning. Is there an easier way to do it other than bashing through the probabilities that the series runs 4,5,6,7 games.

Comment: your question is not clear. Please edit

Comment: What is not clear about it?

Comment: I would instinctively go through the cases. However, I can't help, but feel like there is an easier solution, like you. It seems  like a shifted binomial of some kind, this random variable.

Answer (score 3):

There are $2 \binom{3}{0}$ ways for the game to finish after $4$ rounds.

There are $2 \binom{4}{1}$ ways for the game to finish after $5$ rounds.

There are $2 \binom{5}{2}$ ways for the game to finish after $6$ rounds.

There are $2 \binom{6}{3}$ ways for the game to finish after $7$ rounds.

Quick sanity check
\begin{eqnarray*}
2 \left( \frac{1}{16} +\frac{4}{32} + \frac{10}{64} +\frac{20}{128}  \right) = 1.
\end{eqnarray*}
Right so the expected value is
\begin{eqnarray*}
2 \left( 4\frac{1}{16} +5\frac{4}{32} + 6\frac{10}{64} +7\frac{20}{128}  \right) = \color{red}{5 \frac{13}{16}}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: You accidentally said $5$ rounds instead of $6$ in the third line.